# How to use Device Host API in VB 2010?

Tags: windows, vb6, host, upnp

I'm writing an app in VB 2010 that exposes functionality via UPNP, but I'm completely confused with the Device Host API as MS explains in its site. Does any one have a simple example of how to use this API in VB 2010? Google has failed me and the few examples I found are only of control points.

EDIT: Never mind, the [Developer Tools for UPNP Technologies](http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp) solved my problem faster. So please consider this question solved.